# Installing Oracle JDK 6u38 on Fedora 17 in user home directory

Tags: java, linux, installation

In the older version of Java 6, Oracle provides the `tar.gz` distribution for their JDK, which can be extracted and run in user home directory without installing to system folder. However, the latest versions of Java are no longer distributed as `tar.gz` format for downloading anymore. **Does anyone know how to install the bin distribution in user folder without root privilege?**

I have tried to extract the bin files but it's not usable since most of the jar files are encrypted (or packaged) in some weird format (.pack), e.g. `rt.pack` instead of `rt.jar`. I have also tried to use `--prefix` in the rpm command line but it requires root permission. They seems to make it impossible to install java in user home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-64-self-extracting-142068.html) it says:

> The Java Development Kit files are installed in a directory called
>   jdk.6.0_ in the current directory.

And it looks quite simple, it just says to give execution permissions and execute a bin file.